# Problems creating a jar file using eclipse

Tags: java, c++, jar

I am new to Java and I hope you can help me. I am trying to create a jar for my program and it does not work. I am able to export and create a jar file, but when I click on it just a blank window comes up.

The java has a GUI and I am using 5 differnt buttons to do different functions. One of the buttons is starting a exe file and talking with the exe program using sockets( java is the server and c++ is the client). I have placed the EXE file in the bin. It works fine in the eclipse. Throughout the java I am using `Button.class.getResource` to find the path of different files. There are instances where I have to read image files and I using this function
image = ImageIO.read(file);( I am using this function in the class which is calling the exe )

Before, when I was not linking it with a C++ program, I was able to successfully create a jar file and run it. However I'm not able to do it now, Any help?

> > **EDIT: When running from CMD, this is the error: `enter code here`C:>java -jar simplediptool.jar Exception in thread "main"
> >     java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException    at
> >     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)    at
> >     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
> >     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> >          at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at javax.swing.ImageIcon.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.simplediptool.ScanButton.(ScanButton.java:33)
>           at com.simplediptool.myMainFrame.buildWindow(myMainFrame.java:69)
>           at com.simplediptool.SimpleDiptool.main(SimpleDiptool.java:19)

```
line 32:java.net.URL imageURL = ScanButton.class
                .getResource("images/scan_icon.gif");
line 33:        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imageURL);

line 69:ScanButton scanButton = new ScanButton();

line 19:mainFrame.buildWindow();
```

The simplediptool has the main function. It is calling a method build window from class mainframe, where scanbutton obj is created.

Comment: A blank window means initialization failed and Java (the JVM, or Java runtime) is producing crash messages on standard output (the console). You need to capture this information and submit it here for analysis. Run it from a `cmd` window using a command line invocation.

Comment: Sorry for leaving out this info. Please check the edit

Comment: Please incldue all the relevant `jar tf <jarfile>` output

Comment: Also include the CLASSPATH: `C:> echo %CLASSPATH%`

Answer (score 0):

You're using a relative path in your call to `getResource`. See this for how that's interpreted:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)

EDIT: Given your comment below the problem hasn't been identified yet. I'll leave this as a partial answer for now.

Comment: I used the java.net.URL imageURL = ScanButton.class
                .getResource("/images/scan_icon.gif"); still it does not work.

Comment: I am able to create a runnable jar file if I remove all the instances where I am using ImageIcon. The folder(images) containing the images are in the same package as the class.

Answer (score 0):

I identified my mistake. The image folder containing all the images was not in the src of the project. Therefore,when it was creating the jar file that information was not avalaible. Since the scan button didnot have exception handling for that case, it was giving error.

Thank you for your help.